# PHP: Convert map string into variables

Tags: php

I have a map from jquery:

```
82|81|83|84|85|86|87|88|89
```

I need to cycle through this map and use it in a mysql query, I want to do a while loop so that in the first iteration:

```
$ID = 82; $Position = 1;
```

second iteration:

```
$ID = 81; $Position = 2;
```

third iteration:

```
$ID = 83; $Position = 3;
```

... and so on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = explode('|', $themap);
$length = count($arr);
for($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++){
    // Here $i contains position
    // $arr[$i-1] contains the ID
}
```

PS. I highly recommend **not** putting your query inside the loop unless absolutely needed. It would be better to use a single query. You might be able to use MySQL's `CASE WHEN THEN END` syntax to get what you want in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use `regular expression` or `explode` in PHP.
Code

```
<?php
 $var = "82|81|83|84|85|86|87|88|89";
 $list = preg_split('/[^\d{2}]|\s/', $var);
 print_r($list);
 print_r(explode('|', $var));  
 ?>
```

`Output`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 82
    [1] => 81
    [2] => 83
    [3] => 84
    [4] => 85
    [5] => 86
    [6] => 87
    [7] => 88
    [8] => 89
)
Array
(
    [0] => 82
    [1] => 81
    [2] => 83
    [3] => 84
    [4] => 85
    [5] => 86
    [6] => 87
    [7] => 88
    [8] => 89
 )
```

In this case you can use `explode` but `regex` can solve any complex problem.Try to use it whenever it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could explode it, and use the key+1 as your position value.

```
$vals = explode("|", "82|81|83");

foreach ( $vals as $pos => $val )
  echo 'Position: ' . ($pos+1) . ' Value: ' . $val . '<br/>';

/* Outputs:
   Position: 1 Value: 82
   Position: 2 Value: 81
   Position: 3 Value: 83
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP `explode()` function to split the string into pieces.

```
<?php
    $my_array = explode('|',$input_string);
?>
```

See the manual page here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
<?php

$map_orig = '82|81|83|84|85|86|87|88|89';

$map = explode('|', $map_orig);

foreach ($map as $pos => $item) {
    print '$ID = '.$item.', $Position = '.($pos+1).PHP_EOL;
}
```

will give you the following result:

```
$ID = 82, $Position = 1
$ID = 81, $Position = 2
$ID = 83, $Position = 3
$ID = 84, $Position = 4
$ID = 85, $Position = 5
$ID = 86, $Position = 6
$ID = 87, $Position = 7
$ID = 88, $Position = 8
$ID = 89, $Position = 9
```

See [this CodePad snippet](http://codepad.org/QONsg9zj) for a proof.

Please tell me if you have any questions regarding this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$map = [82, 81, 83, 84,85,86,87,88,89];

for($i=1; $i<=$map.count(); $i++){
   $ID = $map[$i-1];
   $Position = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$map = explode('|', $jQueryMap);
foreach ($map as $position => $ID)
{
    ...
}
```